# Does using more than one semi-colon in JavaScript have any effect?

Tags: javascript, performance, syntax

For example, is:

```
alert('something');
```

The same as:

```
alert('something');;
```

Or does the extra semi-colon cause some sort of "no-op cycle" in the JavaScript engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second semicolon would be interpreted as [*empty statement* <sup>[spec]</sup>](http://es5.github.com/#x12.3). It does not have any effect.

I would believe that engines just ignore it, but that really depends on the engine.

Comment: Thanks :) I also found a link that shows when an "empty statement" might actually affect the flow: [http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch06_19.htm](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch06_19.htm)

Comment: True, you can use the empty statement anywhere where statements are allowed, so also as body of a loop or `if` statement. In these cases it would really be a "do nothing" operation.

Answer (score 0):

NO.Even if you will not give,it is ok.javascript insert comma(,) implicitly.